# Regex To Check If Top Level Domain is .de

Tags: regex

I want to check with regex if a domain name has .de tld.

Such that the following if condition satisfies:-

```
$url = 'google.de';
$regex = '';
if(preg_match($regex, $url)) {
   // url has .de TLD
}
```

Comment: what is `tld` at the last means?

Comment: `TLD` in a domain name `google.de` is `DE`.

Comment: try `$regex = '~\.de$~';`

Comment: seems to be working fine. can you make an answer, so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use end of the line anchor `$` after `\.de` to check for the string `.de` is present at the last.

```
$regex = '~\.de$~';
```